# python delayed execution of print command?

Tags: python, printing

In some part of my python program , I need to do this -

1. print a message on the terminal (using the print command)
2. make some directories (using os.mkdirs)
3. copy a file (using shutil.copy2)
4. Again display a message on terminal (using the print command)

(All this is in a loop)

Now the problem is, although command '1.' is executed before '2.' , '3.' and '4.', it actually displays the message of command '1.' on the screen after all 4 commands have been executed, (along with the message of command '4.'). What I want is that it should display the message of command '1.' first, then start with the remaining piece of code... How can I make this happen? (Is there something like flushing for the print command as well?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flush output of Python print?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)

Comment: Wow, some guy got +62 for knowing about `sys.stdout` and the `.flush` method of file-likes?